# SSIS Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Good afternoon,

Here is a response to a very simple query.  As one can see, these are the parts that go with a claim in our database.

[image]

We have a request to transpose this data so that if a claim has more than 5 parts, then we break the parts up into multiple rows.  So for example, in the example that is listed below, we would get something that looks like this.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction.  I am familiar with the simple SSIS tasks and have done plenty of CSV exports.  I have never seen anything like this so this is a new challenge for me.  Can anyone, please help with how I could accomplish this with SSIS.  One final note, I am not opposed to doing this all in a SQL Server and just then use SSIS to export the data.

**Update 1 - Building Test environments**

```
create table #temp(
RowNo int,
DealerNumber varchar(10),
ClaimId int,
PartNumber varchar(15),
TotalAppPrice decimal(10,2))

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES(1,'095443',226131,'1131655N',0),
(2,'095443',226131,'128483A1',7.4),
(3,'095443',226131,'17277981',0.11),
(4,'095443',226131,'17283181',0.98),
(5,'095443',226131,'17285381',4.65),
(6,'095443',226131,'2830559',20),
(7,'095443',226131,'2831297',103.2),
(8,'095443',226131,'2853800',48.6),
(9,'095443',226131,'2859335',32.75),
(10,'095443',226131,'47368248',18),
(11,'095443',226131,'47522280',0),
(12,'095443',226131,'47821526',68)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? This is often done for reporting reasons, not data integration reasons. If that is the case you are using the wrong tool

Comment: Nick, ultimately the goal is to create a piped data file that will go to the people asking for the data.  This is how they have asked our data to be formatted to work with their systems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If they are loading into a system they are going to have to the reverse work on the other side (assuming they have a sensible data model) Oh well.. I guess you have to do what they ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this in a dataflow,  you'll need to do it in TSQL.

If you get a ROW_NUMBER() that partitions on `ClaimNo` and orders by `RowNo`, you can do integer division to get `GroupRowNo` and MODULO division to get columns 1-5.

You could then have a CTE that looks something like this:

```
ClaimNo   PartNumber   TotalAppPrice  GroupRowNo   ColumnNo
```

Then you would SELECT grouping by `ClaimNo` and `GroupRowNo`, and using conditional aggregation to calculate the 5 columns:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNo=1 THEN PartNumber ELSE NULL END) AS Exp1Desc
```